# SQL Select Query Tree

Tags: mysql, sql, select, recursive-query

I have a table called admin with the following columns:

```
admin_id, 
admin_table, 
unit_id,
unit_table
```

I am beginning a search to see if an admin is over a unit directly or further down the tree. I am starting off with the admin_id, admin_table, unit_id and unit_table. Because the admin may control a unit over an unknown level of descendants.

I need to change the admin_id and admin_table if a unit controlled by the admin is not the searched unit and is an admin over another unit.

How could I do this using an mysql database?

Comment: and you can also go......

Comment: google RECURSIVE CTE

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Guys just because you do not understand something doesn't mean you vote down. Imagine if this was for php. I answered it myself look below:

```
SELECT 
    @uID:=unit_id AS 'unit_id',
    @uTB:=unit_table AS 'unit_table' 
FROM admin
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT @uID:='".$id."', @uTB:='".$table."') TMP
WHERE admin_id=@uID AND admin_table=@uTB')
```